# How I can return the updated row ID in the given code

Tags: php, pdo

This code is working fine for updating the row , but I want to `RETURN` the updated Row ID. Please let me know how I can do that.

```
static function editProject($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }
    $db = new DatabaseConnection();
    $dbh = $db->getDBH();
    $sql = "UPDATE Project SET Job_Name='$JobName',Job_Number='$JobNumber',Location='$Location',
            Project_SupervisorID='$ProjectSupervisorID',Project_ManagerID='$ProjectManagerID',Notes='$Notes',Category='$Category'
            WHERE ID='$ID'";
    $pdo = $dbh->query($sql);
    $db->disconnect();
    return $pdo->rowCount(); // INSTEAD of ROW COUNT RETURN I WANT TO RETURN ID here
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need last insert id of your update query when you already having $ID.

Comment: I need to insert that id into other table for some other purpose

Comment: ID is not the primary key of the table?

Comment: yes, its primary key

Comment: then no need, it will be always $ID

Comment: Otherwise try $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

Comment: Hope your issue is resolved. You can simply return $ID.

Comment: Not yet, $ID is returning empty and $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId(); causing error.

Comment: then it means your update query is not working as you are updating with $ID that is empty.

Comment: Debug your code and check why $ID is empty

Comment: PHP error reporting sounds like it would be useful here. `print_r($arr)` what do you actually have?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike an `insert` with an `update` you already know the `id` of the row you're updating. In your code it is `$ID` so just do

```
return $ID;
```

If you were doing an insert the `pdo` function would be http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

You also should use parameterized queries and prepared statements when using `PDO`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Rough parameterized version:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Project 
        SET Job_Name=?,
            Job_Number=?,
            Location=?,
                Project_SupervisorID=?,
            Project_ManagerID=?,
            Notes=?,
            Category=?
        WHERE ID=?";
$pdo = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute(array($JobName, $JobNumber, $Location, $ProjectSupervisorID, $ProjectManagerID, $Notes, $Category, $ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Update Query, you already have ID so you don't need to know last updated Id.

$ID is the updated ID that you are looking for in your case. So you need to return $ID only.

```
return $ID;
```

Otherwise you can use below PDO Query for getting last updated Id.

```
$pdo = $dbh->lastInsertId();
// If the row exists AND a value is updated, with lastInsertId() you will get the ID of the updated row.
```

Comment: If the row exists AND a value is updated, with lastInsertId() You will get the ID of the updated row :- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me Edit table so that it will automatically keep track of whenever a row is modified.

```
ALTER TABLE Project
ADD lastmodified TIMESTAMP 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then, to find out the last updated row.

```
 SELECT ID FROM Project ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;

   static function editProject($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }
    $db = new DatabaseConnection();
    $dbh = $db->getDBH();
    $sql = "UPDATE Project SET Job_Name='$JobName',Job_Number='$JobNumber',Location='$Location',
            Project_SupervisorID='$ProjectSupervisorID',Project_ManagerID='$ProjectManagerID',Notes='$Notes',Category='$Category'
            WHERE ID='$ID'";
    $pdo = $dbh->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM Project ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;";

    $pdo = $dbh->query($sql);
    $n = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   $db->disconnect();
   return $n['ID'];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [mysql_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

> Returns the value generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous INSERT or UPDATE statement. Use this function after you have performed an INSERT statement into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT field, or have used INSERT or UPDATE to set a column value with LAST_INSERT_ID(expr).

Futhur you can read from above mentioned link